# Exporting classified image from eCognition Essentials Trial license?

Tags: license, ecognition

How do I export a classified image from the eCognition (Objected based) Essentials Trial?

Comment: What kind of image? Export to what format? Add more details, please.

Comment: This question shouldn't really be on hold. The question is clear, and the answer is "you don't - it is disabled in the trial version".

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I'm re-opening so that you can provide that answer

Comment: Ah, i actually managed to get a 1month license for the full version, eCognition developer, but it wont run the NN classification for that either but im not sure why. I must be missing a step? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the trial version of eCognition all functions to export your results have been disabled. Outside of that, no features are unavailable in the trial and there is no time limit.
As such, the short answer is "you do not export images from eCognition Essentials Trial".